# Control python script like linux cli applicaitons

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash

I have a python script which I want to control using linux commands.
e.g. like we control mysql: service mysql restart

How to achieve this kind of functionality.
I saw some bash scripts doing this but don't have any knowledge in bash scripting.
Thanks.

UPDATE:

I have a site_monitor.py script which I included in site_monitor.service in /etc/systemd/system/.

```
[Unit]
Description=Site Monitor Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/hemantsah/WisdomLeaf/site_monitor/site_monitor.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After doing `systemctl daemon-reload.service`, I started the script using `systemctl start site_monitor.service`

Listing all the services using `systemctl list-units --type=service`, I can see the service running, but it's not doing anything.

If I run my python script in terminal using `python3 site_monitor.py`, then it works.

I found just now if I start the service and check the status using `sudo service site_monitor status`,
I checked after starting the service, it was fine , checking after sometime again gave me this error:

```
hemantsah@pop-os:/etc/systemd/system$ sudo service site_monitor status
● site_monitor.service - Site Monitor Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/site_monitor.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-11-18 10:47:30 IST; 16s ago
    Process: 111989 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/hemantsah/WisdomLeaf/site_monitor/site_monitor.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 111989 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 18 10:47:30 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 18 10:47:30 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped Site Monitor Service.
Nov 18 10:47:30 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 18 10:47:30 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 18 10:47:30 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start Site Monitor Service.
Nov 18 10:47:34 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 18 10:47:34 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 18 10:47:34 pop-os systemd[1]: Failed to start Site Monitor Service.
```

Running `sudo journalctl -u site_monitor.service` gave me following error:

```
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os systemd[1]: Stopped Site Monitor Service.
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Site Monitor Service.
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os python3[111023]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os python3[111023]:   File "/home/hemantsah/WisdomLeaf/site_monitor/site_monitor.py", line 3, in <module>
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os python3[111023]:     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os python3[111023]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 18 10:10:37 pop-os systemd[1]: site_monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you already have systemd in your machine, but in case you don't, you can install it via package manager, e.g. `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd
```

You can then, create your own `systemd` service. To do so, just create a new file in `/etc/systemd/systemd/`, something like `/etc/systemd/systemd/your_service_name.service`. That file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description= My service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/working/dir/
User=<user>
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/your/script/<script_name>.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Of course you can use different python 3 binaries instead of `/usr/bin/python3`. Also, the service configuration itself can be different, the example above is just a basic service structure.

After creating this file (with `root` permissions), you should reload the daemon with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And if you want to keep your script enabled even if the server/machine restarts, run:

```
sudo systemctl enable your_service_name.service
```

Finally, you can start your service using the following:

```
sudo systemctl start your_service_name.service
```

Comment: It seems fun, I'm gonna try it now. Thanks for the detailed instructions.

Comment: Hi, I tried this script to run python file, but it is not working, I listed services using systemctl list-units --type=service and my service is running but not working. Could you help me out? I don't see any logs of my python script.

Comment: please, update your question with what you tried and I'll look into it (be sure to write something to distinguish the original question with the update part).

Comment: Could you please add the output of `sudo journalctl -u site_monitor.service`?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question, It says BeautifulSoup is not installed. I will install it.

Comment: it says module not found error for every library, I have installed all the libraries in the python path and not even using virtualenv.

Comment: Hmm. Which python are you using to run the script by yourself? `which python` will output that info.

Comment: Well I use python3 to run scripts manually, But I noticed few things, I have a config.ini file which my python script is not able to read, giving no inputs in python script. On running manually, it's working, I tried changing the absolute/relative path but no help.

Comment: Oh, I will update my answer with one thing that might help (specifying the user). Add it to your file and see if the python modules work now.

Comment: sure, What I tried now is I put os,system("ls -l") inside my python script, when I ran it manually, all related files were showing up, but when I ran as service, those config files are not present. Do you have any solution about this.

Comment: Yes, add the working dir to the systemd service description. I will add it to the answer so you can add it.

Comment: Million Thanks to you, It working now. and I learn something new today.